# HtmlElementView widget gesture issue

Tags: flutter, dart, web

I am trying to build one Flutter screen with HTML text area of height 400px. There may also be multiple Flutter widgets on the same screen with ScrollView. Now the issue is if I'm using HtmlElementView() widget inside the flutter tree, then at that place scroll is not working (means gesture is not recognized). I know if we have html layer below the Flutter widget then we can use pointer_interceptor, but this issue is with scroll detector.`your text`

Need to resolve with same HtmlElementView() widgets, please help me to resolve this.

Remember: - I don't need any layer over HtmlElementView() because it would be editable area.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.